# VBA Code to copy rows based on criteria to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a simple VBA code to pick up complete rows from one sheet and copy them to another sheet based o certain criteria

For example if the first cell in a row contains the text "Cricket" (case insensitive), the system will create a worksheet with the name Cricket, and will copy all rows that fit the criteria to the new worksheet

Below is my attempt, however it's not working as expected

```
Sub officetest()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    If Range("A1,A10000") = "Cricket" Then
        Sheets.Add
        Sheets(2).Name = "Cricket"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1, A10000").Copy 
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    End If
End Sub
```

tried this as well..but not working:

```
Sub officetest()
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    If Range("A1,A10000") = "Cricket" Then
        Sheets.Add Sheets(1).Name = "Cricket"
        Worksheets("Cricket").Range("A, AD").Copy Worksheets(2).Range("A1")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you want all rows that have Cricket in the first cell to be **copied** to a new sheet called Cricket? (your code copies only the first column). Case insensitive?

Comment: Yes..thats right

Comment: I want to copy entire row

Comment: Yes..insensitive...

Comment: Sub officetest()

Worksheets(1).Activate
If Range("A1,A10000") = "Cricket" Then
Sheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Cricket"
Worksheets("Cricket").Range("A, AD").Copy Worksheets(2).Range("A1")

End If

End Sub

Comment: tried this as well..but not working

Answer (score 0):

this is a recorded macro:

i filled first few cells in column A with text (on a blank worksheet)

made one of the cells "cricket"

started macro recorder

selected top left cell ... searched for "cricket"  (searched by columns)

created a new worksheet and named it "cricket"

returned to first sheet selected row with "cricket" ... hit ctrl-c (copy)

selected cricket worksheet ... hit ctrl-v (paste)

stopped macro recorder

this is the resulting macro:

```
Sub Macro2()

    Cells.Find(What:="cricket", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "cricket"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("9:9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("cricket").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

---

here is a quick range addressing example

there are sooooo many ways to refer to a cell and to cell ranges in excel

i included it because, in the rewritten code, the found cell row is referred to as row one

```
Sub lesson()

' note: use F8 to single-step through code

    ' quick example of ranges "inside" other ranges

    Range("b3").Select                     ' cell at B3 is selected
    Range("b3").Range("a2").Select         ' cell at B4 is selected because range(B3) is now a top corner for range(a2)
    Range("b3").Range("a1", "b2").Select   ' range(b3:c4) is selected

End Sub

'  _A_ _B_ _C_                
'1|   |   |   |                
' |_ _|_ _|_ _|
'2|   |   |   |
' |_ _|_ _|_ _|
'3|   |A1 |B1 | <<<<<  range("B3").Range("A1", "B2")
' |_ _|_ _|_ _|
'4|   |A2 |B2 |        cell "B3" is the top left corner of Range("A1", "B2")
' |_ _|_ _|_ _|
'5|   |   |   |
' |_ _|_ _|_ _|
```

---

here is the recorded macro that has been rewritten
to make it shorter

the code has no error checking, so it will crash if search text is not found

you can uncomment the "select" methods
then single-step through the code and see which cells are highlighted by the select statement

note of caution: "foundHere.Select"  method will fail if you do not have the first sheet selected 
(a select method will fail if you try to select a range that is not on an active worksheet

```
Sub findAndCopy()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim foundHere As Range

    Dim findMe As String
    findMe = "cricket"

    Set foundHere = Cells.Find(What:=findMe, After:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

'    foundHere.Select               ' use during debugging only to see if correct cell is being acted on
'    foundHere.Range("1:1").Select

    wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = findMe

    ' note: range("1:1") is first row of range(foundHere) ... see above

    foundHere.Range("1:1").Copy Sheets(findMe).Rows(5) ' copy to row 5 (adjust to your liking)


End Sub
```

i hope that this helps you get started

Comment: This code works as gem and matches perfect when the rows are one with the word/row cricket..Can you guide me on how to modify if there are more rows with the word cricket..and i want all to be cpy and pasted

Answer (score 0):

Copy both of these procedures in a new VBA module and execute "CopyRows()"

First sub will filter all rows using Cricket as the criteria in the first column

Then it will copy all visible rows to the new Sheet named Cricket

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()
    Const ITEM1 As String = "Cricket"
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wsFrom = Sheet1                             '<--- Update this
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set wsDest = CheckNamedSheet(ITEM1)
        With wsFrom.UsedRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & ITEM1
            .Copy   'Copy visible data
        End With
        With wsDest.Cells
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            .Cells(1, 1).Copy
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        wsFrom.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

This function checks if a previous Sheet named Cricket exists, deletes it and creates a new one

```
Private Function CheckNamedSheet(ByVal sheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, result As Boolean, activeWS As Worksheet

    Set activeWS = IIf(ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName, Worksheets(1), ActiveSheet)
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sheetName Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete   'delete sheet if it already exists
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))    'create a new one
    ws.Name = sheetName
    activeWS.Activate
    Set CheckNamedSheet = ws
End Function
```

---

Answer (score 0):

this is just an experiment. i included it because i used it when i needed to figure out "offset" addressing

it may help someone in the future

```
    Sub see_how_offset_works()

        Range("c5").Select                ' C5
        Range("c5").offset(-1).Select     ' C4   previous row
        Range("c5").offset(0).Select      ' C5   same row
        Range("c5").offset(1).Select      ' C6   next row
        Range("c5").offset(1, 1).Select   ' D6   next row and next column

    End Sub
```

---

here is code that may work for you

i have not thoroughly tested the code, and there may be issues because i have not "destroyed" any of the created objects
 eg.  ***set wb = Nothing***

there is no check for sheet name duplication

the program assembles all the data ranges of interest into one range and then does a single copy command to put the data where it is needed

enjoy

---

```
                                   '
    Sub testFind()                 ' !!!!!!!!!!!! run me !!!!!!!!!!!!

        If findData("cricket") Then
            MsgBox "success"
        Else
            MsgBox "text not found"
        End If

    End Sub

    ' ----------------------------------------------------

    Function findData(findme As String) As Boolean      ' returns True if search is successful

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook

        Dim start As Range
        Dim fini As Range
        Dim oneFound As Range
        Dim allFound As Range

        Set start = Range("a1")            ' top of the search range     (must be one column)
        Set fini = Range("a20")            ' bottom of the search range  (must be one column)

    '    Range(start, fini).Select         ' highlight initial search area (debug only ... comment out after debug done)

        Dim indx As Integer
        indx = 0                           ' how far down within the search range do we start the next search

        Dim i As Integer                   ' loop counter
        Dim foundAt As Integer             ' row number where text has been found (this is relative to search range, not relative to worksheet)

        Dim numFinds As Integer            ' how many times is the search text repeated
        numFinds = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(start, fini), findme)  ' count occurences

    '    Debug.Print numFinds
        findData = False                   ' preload the "failure" status

        If numFinds > 0 Then

            For i = 1 To numFinds

                foundAt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(findme, Range(start.offset(indx), fini), 0)

                indx = indx + foundAt - 1        ' indx is the offset from "original top of search range" to the "current found cell"

                start.offset(indx).Select        ' for debugging ... "start.offset(indx)" is the "current found cell"

                Set oneFound = Rows(start.offset(indx).Row)       ' whole row
        '        Set oneFound = start.offset(indx).Range("b1:f1")  ' cells in columns B:F

        '        oneFound.Select                 ' for debugging only

                If i = 1 Then
                    Set allFound = oneFound
                Else
                    Set allFound = Union(allFound, oneFound)  ' assemble all ranges into one range
                End If

        '        allFound.Select                 ' for debugging only
                indx = indx + 1                  ' point to next cell after the "current found cell"
            Next

        '    allFound.Select                     ' for debugging only

        '    allFound.Copy Rows(22)              ' copy selected ranges into row 22 of the current worksheet


            wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = findme  ' this new sheet will have focus

            allFound.Copy Sheets(findme).Rows(5) ' copy to row 5 (change to your liking)

            findData = True                      ' success status

        End If


    End Function
```